# how to get soundcloud follower count using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to put the amount of followers from soundcloud into a JavaScript variable so I can have it ring a notification when I hit 1K follows I have code that I have got from code pen by another user that I have forked
my code is ->  [here](https://codepen.io/SeeGreatness/pen/weJmrY)
and if you do not want to go to see it I have included it below

HTML

```
' <head> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
<div class="card">
<div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-3x"></i>
</div>

<div class="count"></div>
<span>followers</span>
</div>

<audio id="myAudio">
<source src="file:///home/chronos/u-95bb3831b1fe3a2c6fb7e71045f629e9434b1484/Downloads/echoed-ding.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="wright()" type="button">wright</button>
<!--
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button> 
!-->'
```

css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans+Condensed:300);

$primary-font: "Montserrat";
$secondary-font: "Open Sans Condensed";




body {
background-color: #1F282D;

.card {
width: 145px;
height: 187px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .1s opacity;
/*border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 6px;*/

 &.visible {
     opacity: 1;
 }

 .icon {
     position: relative;
     top: .85em;

 }

  .count {
      font-family: $primary-font;
      font-size: 4em;
      line-height: 1em;

      bottom: 0.9em;
  }

  span {
      font-family: $secondary-font;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      letter-spacing: 2px;

      bottom: 1.1em;
  }

  .count, span, .icon i.fa  {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);

      color: #fff;
  }
}
}
```

javascript

```
var abbrev = {
1e3: "K",
1e6: "M"
};

aja()
.method("GET")
.url('https://api.soundcloud.com/users/awesomesauce105?consumer_key=8bcccc3476eaa137a084c9f0c041915f')
.on('200', function(res) {
    var followersCount = res.followers_count;
    Object.keys(abbrev).map(function(k) {
        k = +k;
        if (followersCount > k) {
            var a = followersCount / k,
                 short = a.toString().length > 3 ? Math.round(a * 10) / 10 : a;
            followersCount = short + abbrev[k];
        }
    });
    if (followersCount !== undefined) {
        $(".card .count").text(followersCount);
        $(".card").addClass("visible");
    }
})
.go();
var audio = new Audio('file:///home/chronos/u-95bb3831b1fe3a2c6fb7e71045f629e9434b1484/Downloads/html%205%20up/echoed-ding.mp3');
function playMyAudio() {
audio.play()
}
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
x.pause(); 
} 
function wright(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ;
}
```

My goal is to ring a notification when I hit 1K follows I have a mp3 located on my chromebook at file:///home/chronos/u-95bb3831b1fe3a2c6fb7e71045f629e9434b1484/Downloads/html%205%20up/echoed-ding.mp3
    and I am trying to get it to play a couple of times so I can celebrate. I do not know how to check the amount of followers I have so I used code from someone else but since I did not make it I do not know what is happening in the JavaScript department and thus I cannot just figure it out on my own because I normally would just look up how to run a function when a variable hits a certain variable... and in turn would activate the x.play() to play the sound... if you have any suggestions please let me know thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the Javascript SDK for the Soundcloud API? https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks should do the trick

Comment: is this some interview homework stuff..?

Comment: @vsync nope, I just want to be notified when I become famous lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Soundcloud's Javascript SDK to tap into their API from the client. So add this to your HTML:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID' // edit this with your API credential
  })
</script>
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to receive a "notification" from Soundcloud's API when your followers hit a certain number. Instead, you can write a function that looks up the user periodically, and do something special when the follower count is where you want it. So in your Javascript, something like:

```
function pollSoundcloud (interval) {
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    SC.get('/user/YOUR_USER_ID').then(function (user) {
      if (user.followers_count >= 1000) {
        clearInterval(timer)
        alert('You just reached 1000 followers!') // or do something else
      }
    })
  }, interval)
}

pollSoundcloud(10000) // will check every 10 seconds
```

Comment: thanks for the help so if I am correct the code should look like https://codepen.io/SeeGreatness/pen/OggBQy ? I have got a lot of errors about semicolons and when I try to test the code (by changing the amount of followers to trigger the notification it seems to not work...

Comment: so my user id would be... https://soundcloud.com/awesomesauce105 or awesomesauce105 I got it now it is /user/awesomesauce105